# Objectify like ORM library for GWT

Tags: java, gwt, orm, objectify

We are moving away from Google App Engine, however we are looking for an ORM framework/library which would give us the same productivity as Objectify.
The main advantage being seamless class sharing between GWT and the backend, i.e. no DTOs, just single entity classes.

Is there some ORM that would give us the same level of comfort? i.e. not tricks in serializing on the GWT side, no need for DTO objects, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whatever you want on the server side to persist your classes as long as all the source code of the entities and it's dependencies (annotations, implementing interfaces) are available to the GWT compiler. If you're entities have to extend some sort of magic server side class this is likely not to work.

I recommend giving [Errai](http://www.jboss.org/errai) a try. You can persist your JPA-annotated entities on the server and reuse the same classes on the client.